# Hello is undefined

Tags: html, vbscript

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/vbscript" >
        Function Hello()
        Msgbox "Hello World"
        End Function
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="Hello()" />
</body>
</html>
```

After click on button i am getting Hello is undefined

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Save this code with extension *.hta*

Comment: I am using googecrome and IE also

Comment: Well, vbscript is not compatible with Google Chrome, you should try javascript instead.

Comment: @vitoriahmc I am try in IE also but its not working.

Comment: @Hackoo this is .vbhtml file  when i am going to convert it into .hta it won't work

Comment: @waghya I said : Copy and paste this code and save it as `Test.hta` and not `Test.html` and it will work for you !

Comment: Do not do client-side scripting with VBScript. Even MS browsers don't support it anymore (although there are workarounds). Use JavaScript.

The only way in which I could get the above code to work in IE11 was to set the emulation mode in the developer console to version 8. Obviously, that would not work in Chrome or Safari or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No current browser supports VBScript.

If you want to use it client-side then you need to either:

- Install an old version of Internet Explorer
- Use Internet Explorer 11 and configure it to use the IE 10 Document Mode in the Emulation settings.

---

In general, if you want to do client-side programming in a browser, then you need to be writing JavaScript (or something you can transpile to JavaScript such as TypeScript).